# Is n a Ramanujan number--why am I getting errors in values near 2^63?

Tags: java, largenumber, hardy-ramanujan

Given a number, test to see if it is a Ramanujan number (defined in our course as the sum of two cubes two different ways). It must run in n^(1/3) time.

My code is working--sometimes. As test values approach 2^63 -1 I am getting some random errors.

Weirdly, I was passing this test for numbers in that range before I changed the starting value of a counter to fix a different bug. Can anyone tell me why this might be?

I set up a for loop to create values for a^3.

Then I set values for b=(n-a^3)^(1/3).

Then I test b to see if it is an integer. If so, break the loop.

Inserted an if test here to get the code to work, though I have NO IDEA WHY THIS IS NEEDED, and that's the gist of this question. This if statement sets up two different for loops for values above and below n=2^63

Second loop for n < 2^63, starts off with c=a+1 so I don't duplicate. It's the same as the first one.

Second loop for n > 2^63 starts off with c=a.

Why would this make a difference? Why isn't the same code working for smaller and larger numbers?

Sorry for the babyish code, I am just starting out, and a lot of functions are off limits in my course. (For example, I couldn't use floor() and was not allowed to write my own function for it, either).

```
public class Ramanujan {
public static boolean isRamanujan(long n) {
    if (n <= 0) return false;
    long a3 = 0;
    long c3 = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double d = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a < n; a++) {
        a3 = (long) a * a * a;
        if (a3 > n) break;
        b = Math.cbrt(n - a3);
        if (b == (int) b) break;
    }
    if (n > Math.pow(2, 62)) {
        for (int c = (int) Math.cbrt(a3); c < n; c++) {
            c3 = (long) c * c * c;
            if (c3 > n) break;
            d = Math.cbrt(n - c3);
            if (d == (int) d) break;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int c = (int) Math.cbrt(a3) + 1; c < n; c++) {
            c3 = (long) c * c * c;
            if (c3 > n) break;
            d = Math.cbrt(n - c3);
            if (d == (int) d) break;
        }
    }
    if (a3 + (long) b * b * b == c3 + (long) d * d * d && b * b * b != c3) 
return true;
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long n = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
    StdOut.println(isRamanujan(n));

}
}
```

Any insight as to why I needed to differentiate between larger and smaller numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You'll get weird results when `n` exceeds the value a `long` can hold, i.e. `Math.pow(2, 63) == Long.MAX_VALUE`. At that point, `n` will experience a numerical overflow.

```
final long l = Long.MAX_VALUE; // == 2^63
System.out.println(l); // 9223372036854775807
System.out.println(l + 1); // -9223372036854775808
```

Comment: True, but the values were just below that threshold. The tests used against the program were : Test 13: check isRamanujan() with Ramanujan numbers near 2^63 - 1
  * isRamanujan(9223261564912520489)
  * isRamanujan(9223278330318728221)
==> passed

Answer (score 1):

You get *random* errors for large `int` values because of arithmetic overflow when `Math.cbrt(a3)` or even `Math.cbrt(n - a3)` exceeds the range of type `int`.  You should use type `long` for all integer variables to reduce this possibility and make sure intermediary results do not exceed the range of type `long`.

Here is a simpler implementation using a single loop, computing the number of ways:

```
public class Ramanujan {
    public static boolean isRamanujan(long n) {
        if (n <= 0) return false;
        int count = 0;
        for (long a = 1;; a++) {
            long a3 = a * a * a;
            if (a3 > n - a3) break;
            long b = (long)Math.cbrt(n - a3);
            if (a3 + b * b * b == n) count++;
        }
        return count >= 2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 1) {
            long n = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
            StdOut.println(isRamanujan(n));
        } else
        if (args.length == 2) {
            long n1 = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
            long n2 = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
            for (long n = n1; n <= n2; n++) {
                if (isRamanujan(n))
                    StdOut.println(n);
                if (n == Long.MAX_VALUE) // handle n2 == Long.MAX_VALUE
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            StdOut.println("usage: Ramanujan n1 [n2]");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The largest number a long can hold (in Java) is (2 ^ 63) - 1 (Long.MAX_VALUE).
Why are you calculating Math.cbrt(a3) ? If a3 = a * a * a, then you already know what
Math.cbrt(a3) is.

There is a problem in your code if n > 9223372036854774272
Math.cbrt of 9223372036854774273 is 2097152
and if you cube that you get a negative number because of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with multiplying variables `a and c` of type `int` to calculate the cube. Need to `cast` each of the variable to `long` that is being multiplied.

Example,  `a3 = (long) a * (long) a * (long) a;`